# Cut Paths on a Print File

Tags: print-design, path, gradient

I'm trying to prepare a design in illustrator for print and I'm also going to cut it after printing so I'm adding a cut path around the design and in between the letters, but for some reason it's acting like the gradients on the design are also cut paths. I don't know if anyone knows what I'm talking about or has had this problem.

Comment: Hi Chris Anderson, Is this for a CNC Router?

Comment: No it's for a Roland Sol Jet Pro 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gradients have always been an issue for us on our Rolands.  The ripping software just doesn't interpret them correctly.   I've found the easiest way around this is to hide your cut line, rasterize  your artwork at the resolution and color space of your choice, and show your path again.  Now your artwork is a high resolution bitmap under a vector cut line, but it looks identical to the original AND cuts correctly.  Be sure to keep your original vector version though.

Comment: Thank you so much for the feedback! I think it will help a lot!